# Center four divs in a row bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7**. I have a four divs that have a width base on `col-xs-2` of bootstrap.
*This is my code:*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="first" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 rec">
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 rec">
    </div>
    <div id="third" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 rec">
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 rec">
    sss
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.rec {
  height: 100px;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: blue;
}
#third {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#four {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I wants that the four divs will be in the center of the screen, and I can't achieved it yet - See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptwbn2av/483/

If you have an idea without `col-sm-offset` it will be good also.

Comment: Think you would need to override the bootstrap styles - best bet is to make the cols in that row inline-block and apply text-align center to that row

Comment: Although there is an answer from the duplicate that has a cool codepen showing how to do it using offsets: https://www.codeply.com/go/Sv6Z9eR9kk

Comment: Thanks! After define that in my css it works without any offset! background-color: #ffeeee;
      background-clip: content-box;
      min-height: 80px;